# Forcing a browser refresh on css isn't updating the code with react and antd

Tags: javascript, css, browser-cache, antd

I'm trying to use react and antd in a website. It was all working fine until I tried to integrate video-player. I couldn't get any of the import statements for video-player to load, so I added a link rel=stylesheet to the header of the index.html.

Then -everything disappeared. I can inspect the code in chrome and see that the only css is coming from a body tag in index.js and all the rest has been lost.

I deleted the link from the head tag and have removed and reinstalled antd twice. I have forced refresh on the browser and tried to use incognito and other browsers. They all have lost access to antd.

How can i refresh when all the refresh options aren't working?

Comment: Did you try restarting your application?

Comment: several times. also restarted computer. completely shut down and also restart.

Comment: If you are on localhost long left click on reload button and then clear the caches and hard reload the page, Here is what i am talking about https://i.ibb.co/RCmKD1L/hard-reload.jpg

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you to stay calm and start reading your own code line by line. And, read like it's not your code. Probably, there could be something else error related to spell mistake or incorrect format or something.

Comment: YK - i have tried that several times over